# Macbook notification banner smudge

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

whenever the notification banner that appears on the top right of my screen appears, it's covered by a smudge. I can't find any other other answers online that deals with this problem and it's starting to really annoy me.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @bjbk yeah, just did. only appears for notifications

Comment: it is always there, just not visible if no white background.

Comment: @Buscar웃 the smudge only appears when the notification appears, it vanishes when the notification goes away. you can't see it when there is no notification on the screen

Comment: So if you have a white background or a full screen app it is not there?

Comment: That would be technical not possible. Try some serious cleaning of that area. The "smudge" is clearly outside the Notification pop up area. It does look a lot like finger print.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't know about that. It seems like (a) a software screenshot and (b) the "smudge" is clipped on the left by a mask of some sort

Comment: Is this a smudge on the display itself? If it's software, that's weird for sure

Comment: @Buscar웃 That image is a screenshot, so I can assure you it isn't a fingerprint. It dissapears after the notification goes. The smudge goes past the white area of the notification and covers past it. You can actually see it go over the blue part of my wallpaper.

Comment: Does anyone know why this could possibly be happening? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to completely disable **Notification Center**, reboot, then reenable.

To do so, (with caution, of course) try the following:

- Launch the Terminal app from /Applications/Utilities, enter the following command, and press Return:

`launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist`

- Reboot
- Now re-enable **Notification center**:

`launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist`

---

I have searched in vain to find any information regarding a .plist or other file containing appearance settings for notifications thinking that somehow these had become corrupt.